# jstree: persist tree state while moving one page to other

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am using jsTree with xml approach. I am loading a lot of children on the click of parent node through ajax call. My application contains 4 panels: header , footer , **treepanel** and Main-content. I want persist tree data while moving from one page to other. I have used cookie 
 plugin and its maintaining state but by firing all the ajax call that i have fired at previous pages. I want to persist tree state without firing ajax call while moving one page to other. Please help me to do it.

Comment: You can use offline storage. If your data is not going to be changed frequently.

Comment: can you please elaborate the answer..

Comment: Instead of loading the data from ajax call send an ajax call initially on page load and save the data and then use that data or else save the data in  local storage(see html5 local storage).